# Using regular expressions to parse ip addresses from logs

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression, nmap

I have a large nmap scan containing a number of logs. I'm trying to turn this into a list of ip's only.

When I run my command I receive feedback like the following:

```
Starting Nmap 7.25BETA2 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-03-17 21:27 EDT
Nmap scan report for 10.10.1.22
Host is up (0.13s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
25/tcp open  smtp
MAC Address: 00:50:56:89:7C:D5 (VMware)

Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.72
Host is up (0.22s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
25/tcp open  smtp
MAC Address: 00:50:56:89:55:06 (VMware)
```

I'm trying to retrieve only a list of ip's out of this using the following:

```
nmap -n -p 25 10.11.1.1-254 --open | grep '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d\.\d{1,3}'
```

And I've also tried an awk match:

```
nmap -n -p 25 10.11.1.1-254 --open | awk '/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d\.\d{1,3}/ { print $0 } '
```

Neither return any results despite being able to see an output when I remove everything to the right of my pipe, and also being able to correctly filter for ip's with the regex in my scratchpad.

What piece of knowledge am I missing?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html

Comment: @StephenRauch Are you suggesting the regular exp is the issue? I don't believe that to be the case.

Comment: Yes I am suggesting your regex maybe the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with using the proper output format for Nmap for this type of thing. Nmap's [Grepable output option](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) (`-oG`) produces output in an easy-to-parse format that is consistent between versions, unlike the "human-readable" normal output. Here's how to get the list of all systems with port 25 open:

```
nmap -p 25 --open 10.11.1.1-254 -oG - | awk '/^Host/{print $2}'
```

Nmap will produce a line like this:

```
Host: 64.13.134.52 (scanme.nmap.org)    Ports: 25/open/tcp//smtp///
```

And the awk command will match it based on the "Host" line beginning and print the second field, the IP address.

Answer (score 2):

`\d` is a perl-compatible regular expression (PRCE) extension: your version of `grep` *may* support this with the `-P` option

```
grep -P '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d\.\d{1,3}'
```

Otherwise you can use `[0-9]` for decimal digits; however note that braces are literal in basic regular expressions so you either need extended mode `-E` or must escape them

```
grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

or

```
grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'
```